Are auth code and access token exclusive to a single resource owner?
In my past jobs as an iOS developer, I used authentication url to redirect the resource owner to the authroization server web page on a browser, which allowed the resource owner to login and then consent to the scopes, and then redirect back to the redirect url along with a auth code. This flow was a black box to me and I assumed that the auth code is exclusive for the resource owner. Later ahead exchanging this auth code for a access token, made me assume that the access token is also exclusive for the resource owner
Fast forward..
I have recently started working on a iOS app codebase which uses OAuth to regulate access to resources. In particular we are using Forgerock AM for identity management. The difference is that we are using authenticate url which is not a webpage, but rather a http url request.
The flow I read in the code is

The resource owner enters user id and pass in UITextField.
The resource owner credentials are sent to a authenticate http url request which returns a token id
Then a call to an authorize http url request is made where we pass client id, codechallenge, code method since we use PKCE. This endpoint returned a auth code.
In the end another call to access_token endpoint was made with the authcode and client id and codeverifier, which returns an access token

I was surprised, that no user identity/credential was sent in the third or fourth step above to the auth server requests.
If no user identity was sent to these endpoints, is my earlier assumption that auth code and access token are exclusive to a single resource owner totally wrong?
Are auth code and access token not exclusive to the authenticated resource owner from the second step?

The recent flow you are describing is very suspicious. If it's correct what you are describing, you do have a security issue: the authorization endpoint returns an auth code without authentication of the user. So, anyone can get an auth code!?!? This also is a flaw on the server side, where PKCE - even if the server verifies it - does not help anything. Even if the authorization endpoint would receive the tokenID, the app still receives the password of the user. The whole process makes no sense to me. It seems, a horrible custom login scheme has been built on top of OpenID.

@CouchDeveloper Infact I have the same doubts and that is why my question. Why does the authorize endpoint not have any hint of user id or session and still be able to provide a auth code? Is the auth code not tied to a particular user's id or session?

In OAuth2, the (auth) code is bound to the client (the app). It gives this app permission to fetch an access token and refresh token from the authorisation server. It can be used only once and it expires very shortly after it has been issued. The app acts on behalf of the resource owner (the user who has been authenticated by the authorisation server/IDP). The access token and refresh token must not be shared by the app and kept as secrets. Neither OAuth2 code nor access/refresh token identify the user, or require the user to be present when used.

@CouchDeveloper if the auth code or even the access token is bound only to the client and not in any way associated with a user, then this implies that with the access token I can access resources of anyother resource owner apart from the one who authenticated?

An OAuth2 access token allows the client to access only the user's resources "on behalf" of  the resource owner (aka user). Of course, "on behalf" is only true, if the access token is kept secret within the intended client, and the client is tied somehow to the user.  If it leaks, a malicious attacker could just call the resource endpoints with this access token to obtain this user's resources. An OAuth access token can be validated by the resource server, so that malicious uses can be restricted. In OpenID Connect, there is the "token id" which identifies an authenticated user.

I probably should add, that an OAuth access token is opaque on the client, but not on the resource server. Actually, the access token is frequently a signed JWT, containing sufficient information, including a user's ID, or email, etc., where the resource server then can provide it's service and also guarantee security and the user's consent (the scope, which determines what endpoints the user did allow the client to access). Of course, the server must be implemented correctly as well, which we take as granted, possibly too often.

In both cases you are describing an OAuth Authorisation Code grant.
In the first case it is browser based where your app does not have access to the user credentials. In the second case it is "browserless" and your app obtains the credentials and submits them directly.
In both cases, at the end of the authorisation step, you have an authorisation code that is valid for a limited time and a single use.
The authorisation code is exchanged for an access token (and in some cases also a refresh token that can be used to obtain additional access tokens)
The authorisation code doesn't identify a user per-se, but rather a successful user authentication session (which is associated with a user identity).
In your second flow, the Authorization Grant is combined with PKCE, which is used to provide assurance that the authorisation code is being presented by the party to whom it was provided to protect against MITM attacks.
In the Forgerock implementation, the authorisation code is sent in a cookie, rather than as a request parameter or in a the request body.
The process is described here.

in the second flow there is now browser involved. Since we are the service providers and it is our own app, we take the users credentials on a native view. After this we authenticate(user id and pass) the user, but during the authorize phase(to get auth code) I dont see any user identifier or user session identifier being sent to the authorize endpoint. This leads me to the question, how is the auth code or the access token connected to a user id or user session

Ok. The process is described here  https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/7/oauth2-guide/oauth2-implicit-grant.html  Step 2 is an implicit grant. It returns a token. In step 3, this token is sent in a cookie

An implicit flow is used for web apps using a scripting language (so, not React native, for example). There is no intermediate code in this case, and the web app gets directly the access token, and PKCE cannot be used also. This flow has security implications (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-10.3, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-10.16)

Yes, sorry. It isn't actually an implicit flow. It is a browser less authorization code flow. Updated

@Paulw11 Thanks for pointing out the forgerock doc that mentions that the user session is stored in a cookie. I verified that the cookie was stored after authenticate call was completed and then it was sent in the request to authroize and get auth code. This was the missing link. Maybe you can shorten your answer to be more precise. I will accept it
